# Override Phonegap default splash screen using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, splash-screen

I use jQuery Mobile with HTML5 and CSS3.
When I upload my code to PhoneGap cloud build servers and place the app on my iPhone and start the app, I see the following splashscreen: [image]

The question now is: how can I override this image? 
Do note: I'm not using a regular phonegap project (e.g. in Visual Studio), but just an index.html file with js and css files.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. My app is visible in bottom behind splash screen, but splash screen is stuck with loading symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get some valuable information from [here](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml). This is from official Phonegap team. Also you can look into [this](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36905973/Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens) too.

Hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Apple now requires a splash image.  So if you don't include one in your config file on Phonegap Build, then the compiler inserts that ugly default version for you.  So the solution is to make sure that you use your own custom splash image and specify that custom image with appropriate settings in the config file.  You should be fine after that.

https://build.phonegap.com/blog/new-apple-app-store-submittal-rules

> If a splash screen is not found in your package the PhoneGap default
>   image will be used, so be sure to include your splash screen in all
>   the required dimensions for your device. Apple has a handy guide to
>   these dimensions here.